# React Native Expo FileSystem, how can I save while setting the priority to very high? And do i need permision to save elswhere than cache folder?

Tags: react-native, image, expo, save, filesystems

I liked save image file with the aim to keep the image as long as possible in the device.

Searched for flags to set priority high.
Saved file to chache Folder but the file always get deleted by system.

How can i have the file stay as long as possibly

EDIT:

Code example.

```
FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      imgUrl,
      FileSystem.cacheDirectory +
        saveImagesDirectory +
        shortHash(imgUrl)
    )
```

But i need to save it as high priotity or at least the pictures should be saved for a long time and not always be removed from the system so quickly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.